# Permanent storage in GCP Cloud Shell lost

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-shell

Google Cloud Platform (GCP) offers an interactive shell with free permanent storage of 5GB.
The only condition to keep it is to connect to it at least every 90 days.
If you let this time pass, you are supposed to receive a warning email before your storage disappears.
This summer, I missed the 90 days and did not see or receive this alert email.
My permanent storage is gone: weary:
Does anyone have an idea to find it?
Thank you

Comment: Don't count on anything in Google Cloud Shell. It's just a convenience feature; you should normally be working from your own workstation.

Answer (score 2):

As you mention this is a limitation in Cloud Shell itself and it's depicted in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/limitations#usage_limits), as such, it won't be possible for you to recover the information you had on the disk if you missed the deletion date.

For future cases, I would suggest you save your information towards Cloud Storage or use a normal GCE instance in case you prefer working through a VM so that you don't have to worry about this.